# Shutdown: waiting for program to close

Tags: windows-7, shutdown, truecrypt

When I press the shutdown button Windows will happily reject the shutdown no matter which trivial program/task that asks for more time.
When I press the physical shutdown button I want windows to shutdown no matter what, with the exception of veracrypt that needs enough time to re-encrypt drives, clear keys from memory and whatever else it does on exit.

Is this achieveable?

(global force shutdown is obviously not an option with veracrypt needing a proper shutdown)

Comment: Mind specifying the version of Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason I asked you above about the version of Windows you're using is because your claim that "When I press the shutdown button Windows will happily reject the shutdown no matter which trivial program/task <strike>that</strike> asks for more time" is simply not true for any version after XP.

As Raymond Chen talks about in [Changes to power management in Windows Vista](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/04/16/2148139.aspx) and [Now that Windows makes it harder for your program to block shutdown, how do you block shutdown?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/06/14/10319617.aspx), from Vista onwards only apps that implement the  **Shutdown­Block­Reason­Create()** function can block the shut down process once it's been initiated, and even then the user can always choose to forcibly shut down no matter what. This was done to prevent that old problem where people (especially laptop users) used to initiate shut down, only to find later that the system remained on all along because it was stuck due to some app and thus had heated up or had exhausted the battery.

You can test this very easily. Open a bunch of apps that do not allow you to close them if there are unsaved changes. For example Notepad, Paint, Word and so on that all throw up "Do you want to save?" type dialogs. Now if you've set the power button to shut down and you press it, you'll see a window displaying all the open apps, and they *will* be killed regardless of whether you very quickly save your work or not.

I have come across no consumer apps so far that abuse Shutdown­Block­Reason­Create() to prevent Windows from shutting down. That's not to say that no such misbehaved apps exist, but your claim that every trivial program can block Windows shut down is just not true any more. If you are indeed experiencing this then there's clearly something wrong at your end because that's not the way Windows is supposed to behave (and does) since Vista.

Comment: Windows 7, if I get enter a IRC chat on firefox and shutdown it will notify me of chat disconnect and windows shutdown will wait. I didn't wait more than 15 sec before I had enough. Either way, I want the computer to force shutdown everything except veracrypt. That's the goal here, not to wait 30 or even 10 seconds for shutdown initatiation.

Comment: Windows will force shut down everything eventually if you wait long enough. There's no way to "protect" VeraCrypt specifically unless the program itself implements both Shutdown­Block­Reason­Create() and Shutdown­Block­Reason­Destroy() properly (it's open source so you can add it if you want and are capable of doing so). Without those functions VeraCrypt is at the mercy of Windows and has at most 2 secs. I believe to finish all its work and close cleanly after it receives the termination signal from the OS.